# How can I randomize order of cucumber example steps=

Tags: selenium, cucumber

How can I randomize the fastest method /way to do?: 
 Scenario Outline: As an Piet i can delete users
    Given the user is logged in as 'Piet'
    Given the menu item 'user management' is selected
    When the user '' is deleted
    Then the notification panel contains the message 'Deze gebruiker is 
  succesvol verwijderd.'
    And the notification panel contains no errors

## randomize order of delete

```
Examples: User accounts to delete
  | username      |
  | hans          |
  | piet          |
  | kees          |
  | jan           |
```

I expected Cucumber to support something like this: (but apparently it doesn't , at least not yet)
 Scenario Outline: As an Piet i can delete users
    Given the user is logged in as 'PIET'
    Given the menu item 'user management' is selected
    When the user '' is deleted
    Then the notification panel contains the message 'Deze gebruiker is 
 verwijderd.'
    And the notification contains no errors

## randomize order of delete

```
Examples: User accounts to delete
  | username [RANDOM] |
  | hans              |
  | piet              |
  | kees              |
  | jan               |
```

so what is the best way to get these steps run in a random order?

Answer (score 2):

This is a total hack way of doing this. But it works.

Place all the users inside the scenario. Examples table contains the countdown.

```
Scenario Outline:
    When Users to be deleted "one,two,three,four,five"
    Then Delete random user <num>

    Examples:
    | num |
    |5|
    |4|
    |3|
    |2|
    |1|
```

---

Stepdefinition code. This is in Cucumber 3.0.2, modify accordingly if on Cucumber 2 or below.

```
    private static List<String> delUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> userList= new ArrayList<>();

    @When("Users to be deleted {string}")
    public void userDel(String users) {
        System.out.println("------------");
        System.out.println("Deleted users - "+delUserList);
        userList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(users.split(",")));
        userList.removeIf(delUserList::contains);
        System.out.println("Remaining users - "+userList);
    }

    @Then("Delete random user {int}")
    public void delRandom(int num) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int ind = rand.nextInt(num);
        System.out.println("User to delete - "+userList.get(ind));
        delUserList.add(userList.get(ind));
    }
```